# How much does it cost to deploy a smart contract on Ethereum mainnet?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment, javascript

I've just completed building my first smart contract in Solidity and I am ready to deploy to the public.

I want to deploy to mainnet but I'm being told that I don't have enough funds to deploy. On the dry run, it says the total cost is `0.00178154 ETH`, around $4.

But on the actual deployment I get the following error from truffle:

```
"Migrations" could not deploy due to insufficient funds
   * Account:  <redacted>
   * Balance:  38271570000000000 wei
   * Message:  insufficient funds for gas * price + value
```

The wallet it's being deployed with has `0.0383 ETH` (around $87) in it. Is this not enough to deploy a very small smart contract? If so, how much should it cost? This seems a little crazy if so.

Also here is the `truffle-config.js`...

```js
require('dotenv').config()
require('babel-register')
require('babel-polyfill')

const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider')

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: '127.0.0.1',
      port: 7545,
      network_id: '*'
    },
    mainnet: {
      provider: () => new HDWalletProvider({
        privateKeys: [process.env.PK],
        providerOrUrl: "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/" + process.env.INFURA_PROJECT_ID
      }),
      network_id: 1
    }
  },
  contracts_directory: './contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory: './abis/',
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The migrations contract is as follows:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

Comment: did you find solution to your problem? im having the same problem right now. not enough funds, but on testnet, i can deploy and upgrade smart contract without problem and uses less fund.